# Print a variable in hexadecimal in Python

Tags: python, string, hex

I'm trying to find a way to print a string in hexadecimal. For example, I have this string which I then convert to its hexadecimal value.

```
my_string = "deadbeef"
my_hex = my_string.decode('hex')
```

How can I print `my_hex` as `0xde 0xad 0xbe 0xef`?

To make my question clear... Let's say I have some data like `0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04` stored in a variable. Now I need to print it in hexadecimal so that I can read it. I guess I am looking for a Python equivalent of `printf("%02x", my_hex)`. I know there is `print '{0:x}'.format()`, but that won't work with `my_hex` and it also won't pad with zeroes.

Comment: See also: [Printing a Python list with hex elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48162852/4561887).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You mean you have a string of *bytes* in `my_hex` which you want to print out as hex numbers, right? E.g., let's take your example:

```
>>> my_string = "deadbeef"
>>> my_hex = my_string.decode('hex')  # python 2 only
>>> print my_hex
Þ ­ ¾ ï
```

This construction only works on Python 2; but you could write the same string as a literal, in either Python 2 or Python 3, like this:

```
my_hex = "\xde\xad\xbe\xef"
```

So, to the answer. Here's one way to print the bytes as hex integers:

```
>>> print " ".join(hex(ord(n)) for n in my_hex)
0xde 0xad 0xbe 0xef
```

The comprehension breaks the string into bytes, `ord()` converts each byte to the corresponding integer, and `hex()` formats each integer in the from `0x##`. Then we add spaces in between.

Bonus: If you use this method with unicode strings (or Python 3 strings), the comprehension will give you unicode characters (not bytes), and you'll get the appropriate hex values even if they're larger than two digits.

#### Addendum: Byte strings

In Python 3 it is more likely you'll want to do this with a byte string; in that case, the comprehension already returns ints, so you have to leave out the `ord()` part and simply call `hex()` on them:

```
>>> my_hex = b'\xde\xad\xbe\xef'
>>> print(" ".join(hex(n) for n in my_hex))
0xde 0xad 0xbe 0xef
```

Comment: Just to note this won't work on Python 3.x, while the `unhexlify`solution will...

Comment: @alexis the `.decode` as `str` no longer has a `decode` as it's not necessary.... and `b'deadbeef'.decode('hex')` won't work as `hex` encoding has been removed

Comment: But that's just how the OP constructed the string: It's not part of the answer. `hex(ord(c))` will still convert a byte into a two-digit hex number.

Answer (score 13):

Another answer with later print/format style is:

```
res[0]=12
res[1]=23
print("my num is 0x{0:02x}{1:02x}".format(res[0],res[1]))
```

Answer (score 9):

Convert the string to an integer base 16 then to hexadecimal.

```
print hex(int(string, base=16))
```

These are built-in functions.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int

Example

```
>>> string = 'AA'
>>> _int = int(string, base=16)
>>> _hex = hex(_int)
>>> print _int
170
>>> print _hex
0xaa
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
print " ".join("0x%s"%my_string[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(my_string), 2))
```

like this:

```
>>> my_string = "deadbeef"
>>> print " ".join("0x%s"%my_string[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(my_string), 2))
0xde 0xad 0xbe 0xef
>>>
```

On an unrelated side note ... using `string` as a variable name even as an example variable name is very bad practice.

Comment: This looks like splitting a string into pairs of characters. I don't need that.

Comment: +1 for calling out using `string` as a variable name.  Overwriting base types with variables can lead to incredibly frustrating debugging, trust me.

Comment: @Valdogg21: `string` isn't a base type-- that's `str`.  It is the name of a stdlib module, however.

Comment: @DSM Woops.  Major duh moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this I guess:

```
new_str = ""
str_value = "rojbasr"
for i in str_value:
    new_str += "0x%s " % (i.encode('hex'))
print new_str
```

Your output would be something like this:

```
0x72 0x6f 0x6a 0x62 0x61 0x73 0x72
```

Comment: I though he wanted to translate a string into hex and not to divide it into pairs of 2 . Its my fault that i didn't saw the example output

Comment: Not your fault, if you look at the history you'll see that the original question read that way. The OP couldn't decide what to name his/her variables, but I think I fixed it for him/her...

Answer (score 1):

A way that will fail if your input string isn't valid pairs of hex characters...:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> ' '.join(hex(ord(i)) for i in binascii.unhexlify('deadbeef'))
'0xde 0xad 0xbe 0xef'
```