# Printing a Python list with hex elements

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
a_list = [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]
```

When I print it, I get:

```
print a_list
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

But I want:`[0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0]` or `[0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]`, it doesn't matter for now.

I've tried to create a function such as:

```
def hex_print(the_list):
     string = '['
     for element in the_list:
         if(the_list.index(element) < len(the_list)):
             print(str(the_list.index(element)))
             string = string + hex(element) + ', '
         else:
             print(str(the_list.index(element)))
             string = string + hex(element) + ']'
     print string
```

But every time the printed message is:

```
[0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
```

I think that the_list.index(element) always returns the first occurrence of element in the_list and not the actual position of the element. Is there a way where I can get the actual position of the element?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
>>> a_list = range(4)
>>> print '[{}]'.format(', '.join(hex(x) for x in a_list))
[0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3]
```

This has the advantage of not putting quotes around all the elements, so it produces a valid literal for a list of numbers.

Comment: Since I want leading zeros on my byte values less than 0x10, I use:
    print ('[{}]'.format(', '.join(f"0x{x:02x}" for x in a_list)))

Answer (score 10):

### Python 3

For python 3:

```py
print(list(map(hex, a_list)))
```

example: http://codepad.org/NHFlLslj

---

### Python 2

For python 2:

```
print [hex(x) for x in a_list]
```

The output shall be something like: http://codepad.org/56Vtgofl

Comment: This gives an error when done in Python 3.

Answer (score 7):

```
print [hex(no) for no in a_list]
```

`hex` function converts a number to its hexadecimal representation.

Comment: This gives an error when done in Python 3.

Answer (score 7):

For python3, use following code:

```
print([hex(x) for x in a_list])
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want zero padding:

```
", ".join("0x{:04x}".format(num) for num in a_list)
```

The "0x{:04x}" puts the "0x" in front of the number.  The "{:04x}" part pads zeros to 4 places, printing the number in hex.