# Is there a way to print all values of a complex structure in hexadecimal format without loops, in python?

Tags: python, formatting

I sometimes have to print complex structures, such as list of tuples, say:

```
lst = [(101, 102), (103, 104)]
print(lst)
[(101, 102), (103, 104)]
```

I want the print to be formated in hexadecimal, ideally something like:

```
print(lst.hex())
[(0x65, 0x66), (0x67, 0x68)]
```

If I had a simple list, [I could write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783962/printing-a-python-list-with-hex-elements):

```
>>> a_list = range(4)
>>> print '[{}]'.format(', '.join(hex(x) for x in a_list))
[0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3]
```

So I assume with nested list comprehension or multivariable ones, I could managed it thought I barely know how thought I have read several Q/A on the subject here.

So, is there a simple way to do it, independent of the structure complexity?

Comment: Does the ```for x in a_list``` in the comprehension count as a loop to you?

Comment: you could use recursion to go through the various elements checking if there are  lists inside of lists

Comment: Yes because then, as explained, it is dependent of the structure. Imagine I have a list oflist of tuples

Comment: @Andrew, I can write a recursive function, yes, but it would be defined with loops. I don't know if my question has a solution

Comment: @lalebarde so you are unable to use any loops at all to try and solve this? or just nested loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the normal string representation of the structure and convert all numbers to hexadecimal using regex:

```
import re
lst = [[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(5, 6), (7, 8)]]
print(re.sub(r'\d+', lambda match: hex(int(match.group())), str(lst)))
```

Outputs:

```
[[(0x1, 0x2), (0x3, 0x4)], [(0x5, 0x6), (0x7, 0x8)]]
```

The upside to this is that it is not dependent on the structure at all. It simply looks for numbers in the string representation of the list and replaces them with their hexadecimal value. This allows it to tackle any combination of lists, tuples, and ints E.g.:

```
import re
lst = [(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(5, 6), (7, 8)], [[1]], 1234, 1, [(99)]
print(re.sub(r'\d+', lambda match: hex(int(match.group())), str(lst)))
```

Outputs:

```
[[(0x1, 0x2), (0x3, 0x4)], [(0x5, 0x6), (0x7, 0x8)], [[0x1]], 0x4d2, 0x1, [0x63]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Andrew Ryan's idea, here is a solution that relies on recursion rather than iteration:

```
lst = [(101, 102), (103, 104)]


def recursive_convert(l, i=0):
    if type(l) == list:
        x = l.pop(i)
        l.insert(i, recursive_convert(x))
        if i+1 < len(l):
            return recursive_convert(l,i+1)
        return l
    elif type(l) == tuple:
        l = (hex(l[0]), hex(l[1]))
        return l
    


print(recursive_convert(lst))
```

Note that this assumes some things, like the number of elements in the tuple as well as knowledge of the data structure that's in the list.

Output:

```
[('0x65', '0x66'), ('0x67', '0x68')]
```

Answer (score 1):

how about using list comprehension?

```
lst = [(101, 102), (103, 104)]
print([(hex(x),hex(y)) for x,y in lst])
```

output:

```
>> [('0x65', '0x66'), ('0x67', '0x68')]
```

or you can use NumPy printoption:

```
import numpy as np
lst = [(101, 102), (103, 104)]
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int':hex})
print(np.array(lst))
```