# Python's Scapy can't print load

Tags: python-2.7, scapy, payload, packets

I am new to Scapy, I recently tried creating a program that would search for packets and print them.

When I ran the program,

```
from scapy.all import *
a = sniff(iface='enp0s3', count=1)
l = a[0].load
print l
```

it gave the output of

```
!f��B    2�.�I�b��"�����.�KS���
```

However, when running the program in the interactive Scapy shell, running

```
a[0].load
```

it gives:

```
\x17\x03\x03\x00!f\x1d\xf3\xb0B\x15\t2\x86.\xcbI\xddb\xaa\xf1"\x03\xf1\x8c\x91\xda\xd3.\xf3\x08\xe7K\x05S\xfe\x96\xac
```

This is the payload of a packet. How can I convert the symbols outputted from the script to something like what I got when running it in the interactive shell?

Comment: this is happening because of character encoding

Comment: is there anyway to convert it

Comment: What information are you looking to get from the packet?  Can you use show()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
print " ".join(hex(ord(n)) for n in a[0].load)
```

Source: *[Print a variable in hexadecimal in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572008/print-a-variable-in-hexadecimal-in-python)*